# PHP - Secured Websockets with cPanel and a pem file

Tags: php, websocket, wss, pem

I am using the [Lets Encrypt for cPanel](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/The+Let%27s+Encrypt+Plugin) plugin to use a signed certificate for my https website. Before I started using this, my created websocket server did worked like a charm. However, after using HTTPS I was forced to use secured sockets (WSS) to connect with my websocket server which is written in PHP.

In order to make use of WSS I have to install a PEM file. Since cPanel does not provide me a PEM file I'm a little bit confused. How do I generate such PEM file?

I've got an [example](https://github.com/nekudo/php-websocket/blob/master/server/server.pem) of how the PEM file should look like. So I copied the code of the certificate generated by Lets Encrypt into a empty file with a PEM extension but now I need a RSA private key. Should I use the one of SSH access or should I generate a new RSA key?

Also, I can create a websocket server succesfully with the self generated PEM file, but however, I can't connect to this server with the browser because the buffer can't be read (returns 0 bytes).

Would be nice if someone could tell me how to generate a proper PEM file so I can install that for the secured websocket connection. My PHP websocket server is exactly the same as the linked repository of the PEM file example.

Answer (score 1):

After some nights of good sleep I found the solution myself, its not that hard actually.

Lets Encrypt creates a folder inside "public_html" called "ssl". Inside that folder you can find the *.crt and *.key files. Copy the content of it into a new *.pem file and upload this pem file to the server. Now you can use secured websockets.

Comment: I have the same issue and I cannot work out how you managed to keep the SSL path correct after each renewal because in my case the key and pem change their names every 60 days.